# How to get mobile device data from a http request?

Tags: c#, android, .net, http, asp.net-web-api2

I've built a web api that is called via an application (iOS/Android) through HTTP requests. I'm trying to implement a GET request that returns different data based on the device, OS, application version, .. etc. I've been using UserAgent with IOS devices and it's working just fine, it goes like that:

```
        var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();

        var clientInfo = uaParser.Parse(Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString());
```

Also if I opened the request via browser it also returns the data. Example of the response is: **UserAgent: Windows 10 Other Chrome 63.0.3239**

The problem is in the Android devices, it doesn't send any data about neither the device nor the OS, and I don't want to hard code the details in the android apps, I believe they are sent somewhere as [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) can show these details for both iOS and Android.

Is there is any possible solution to get this data from the requests itself?

Answer (score -1):

If you really wana do that then you could programically get android device name and its version and send it to your server as a parameter in http request...

**To get Device Name**

```
String devName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

**To get Version code**

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Then You Could Easily Send Them To Your Server As  A Parameter In Your Request And Store Them To Database etc....
Hope This Helps ! Cheers !

Comment: thanks for that, the problem is as I said, we could start to tell android team to send this data programically and we start to use that, while those same requests, have already this data send somehow that I don't know how to access it! my evidence on that: we are using Crashlytics and it shows all the data about the android devices in these requests, this proves that they don't need to send them by themselves it's already sent.

Comment: if you wana verify if data is really getting sent then you better try any good mitm proxy like fiddler to verify it